# Model laravel retorn null e não a classe do model

Tags: laravel

tenho o model abaixo e quando faço uma pesquisa que tem dados, funciona certo, mas quando não tem ele retorna null, não era pra retornar a classe do modelo vazia, sem preencher os dados?

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AreaInteresse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'ZPVOBJETIVOINTERESSE';

    protected $fillable = [
        'cpf',
        'nivel',
        'area',
    ];
}
```

estou fazendo a pesquisa assim:

```
$areasInteresse = AreaInteresse::where('cpf', '=', Auth::user()->cpf)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Você poderia me informar para que vai utilizar estes dados? Porque o retorno não poderia ser null? Por padrão quando não tem dados retorna null mesmo, está correto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno esta correto.

Está retornado *null* pois a função *where()* não retorna a própria classe, mas sim uma instância do *QueryBuilder*.

Uma forma de contornar isto seria usando *[local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes)* recomendo dar uma lida.

**Adendo:** Vou deixar este adendo e altero conforme a resposta do comentário.

Se você estiver com problema no retorno *null*, pois está prejudicando quando passa a variável para *view* você pode usar o seguinte código na sua *view*:

```
@if($areasInteresse->isEmpty())
    {{--Código que vai usar $areasInteresse aqui--}}
@endif
```

Isto faz com que não entre neste trecho do código se a saída for nula.

Comment: muito obrigado era esse mesmo o problema!